# What is meant by " Ubuntu server using MySQL and apache Tomcat 7 "

Tags: apache, ubuntu, tomcat7

My project is " Deploy your project " On-line Travel Deal : on an Ubuntu server using MySQL and Apache Tomcat 7 ..

What is meant by .. " Ubuntu server using MySQL and Apache Tomcat 7 " ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A computer running a Linux distribution called Ubuntu (http://www.ubuntu.com) with the MySQL Database Server installed (http://www.mysql.org) with the Apache Tomcat Java application server also installed (http://tomcat.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

It means a set of:

- [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server)

- MySQL for Ubuntu (Choose link for Ubuntu Linux: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ ), or install from command `sudo apt-get install....` ( https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mysql.html )

- Apache Tomcat 7 ( http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi  or using command line: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-apt-get)